# How can I fix this apt kernal-image state?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

The update manager hung during a recent Ubuntu update and I had to kill it. This left a couple of lock files in `/var/...` which I deleted.

I now have a lot of scary errors.

If I run `dpkg --configure -a`

```
Setting up linux-image-3.16.0-25-generic (3.16.0-25.33) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-25-generic
) points to /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-25-generic
 (/boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-25-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-25-generic.postinst line 491.
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-25-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-25-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-25-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-25-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.16.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-25-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.16.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.16.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-25-generic
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-25-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.16.0-25-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up flashplugin-installer (11.2.202.424ubuntu0.14.10.1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package flashplugin-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.16.0-25-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.16.0-25-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.16.0.25.26); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up popcorn-time (0.3.5.2-1~webupd8~1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package popcorn-time (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-3.16.0-25-generic:
 linux-signed-image-3.16.0-25-generic depends on linux-image-3.16.0-25-generic (= 3.16.0-25.33); however:
  Package linux-image-3.16.0-25-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-3.16.0-25-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.16.0-25-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-25-generic depends on linux-image-3.16.0-25-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.16.0-25-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-25-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-generic:
 linux-signed-image-generic depends on linux-signed-image-3.16.0-25-generic; however:
  Package linux-signed-image-3.16.0-25-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-generic:
 linux-signed-generic depends on linux-signed-image-generic (= 3.16.0.25.26); however:
  Package linux-signed-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.16.0-25-generic
 flashplugin-installer
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 popcorn-time
 linux-signed-image-3.16.0-25-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-25-generic
 linux-signed-image-generic
 linux-signed-generic
```

If I run `apt-get install -f`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  linux-image-3.16.0-23-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-23-generic
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 2 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
11 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 203 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 155164 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.16.0-23-generic (3.16.0-23.31) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.16.0-23-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.16.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.16.0-23-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.16.0-23-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.16.0-23-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.16.0-23-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.16.0-23-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.16.0-23-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.16.0-23-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.16.0-23-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-23-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.16.0-23-generic: No such file or directory
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic
Device driver support needs thus be built-in linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_VBNOPy/lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_VBNOPy/lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.16.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.16.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-23-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.16.0-23-generic (3.16.0-23.31) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-23-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.16.0-23-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-23-generic
 linux-image-3.16.0-23-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I run `apt-get autoremove`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  efibootmgr grub-efi-amd64-bin libefivar0 linux-headers-3.16.0-23 linux-headers-3.16.0-23-generic linux-image-3.16.0-23-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-23-generic secureboot-db shim
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 9 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
9 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 286 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 184852 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing grub-efi-amd64-bin (2.02~beta2-15) ...
Removing efibootmgr (0.7.0-2) ...
Removing libefivar0:amd64 (0.10-5) ...
Removing linux-headers-3.16.0-23-generic (3.16.0-23.31) ...
Removing linux-headers-3.16.0-23 (3.16.0-23.31) ...
Removing linux-image-extra-3.16.0-23-generic (3.16.0-23.31) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.16.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.16.0-23-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.16.0-23-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.16.0-23-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.16.0-23-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.16.0-23-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.16.0-23-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.16.0-23-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.16.0-23-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.16.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.16.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-23-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.16.0-23-generic (3.16.0-23.31) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/prerm.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/prerm.d/dkms 3.16.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/prerm.d/last-good-boot 3.16.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-23-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.16.0-23-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing secureboot-db (1.1) ...
Removing shim (0.7-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-10ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-23-generic
 linux-image-3.16.0-23-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

These commands tend to leave these files behind afterwards

```
/var/lib/dpkg/lock
/var/lib/apt/lists/lock
/var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

I'm wary of rebooting before I can fix this. What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors persisted until I *installed* something (`libav-tools`) after which `apt-get autoremove` succeeded and all the others went away after that. I have no idea why this worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to `apt-get install` anything, either—I get `Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic (3.13.0-43.72) ...` and `depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-43-generic: No such file or directory`. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: I solved my problem by force-installing the broken kernel module, i.e. `apt-get install -f linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic`. apt-get works again now. Details here: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=185281

Comment: I've got an ubuntu 12.04 LTS server that has unattended security updates applied, and this broke on the same kernel version. coincidence? who knows. I noticed because `update-initramfs -u` was throwing errors when trying to set up a new encrypted disk for it

Comment: er I mean 14.04LTS